# how to use Docx.NET make cell fill color?

Tags: c#, docx, python-docx

I use Xceed.Words.NET, I need set some cell fill color:

```
cell.FillColor = Color.Blue;
OR
cell.Shading = Color.Blue;
```

I found the cell has not really been fill color, and I found that if the cell has fill color in Word, then I can reset it, I checked the xml:

// can't reset fill color

```
<w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="FFFFFF" w:themeFill="background1" />
```

// can reset fill color, because it has fill color in Word

```
<w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="12A400" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution:
[Alpha channel of the FillColor loss #279](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX/issues/279)

```
public static void FillColor(Cell cell, Color color)
{
    var w = cell.Xml.Name.Namespace;
    var shd = cell.Xml.Element(w + "tcPr").Element(w + "shd");
    shd.Attribute(w + "themeFill").Remove();
    cell.FillColor = color;
}
```